# Call to a member function where() on a non-object Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am attempting to use and `id` that being passed into the `URL` to edit the query but when attempting to run the code I get an error of:

> Call to a member function where() on a non-object

## Controller

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function showWelcome() {
        $id = intval($_GET['wab_id']);
        $results = DB::Table('films')->get()->where('wab_id','=', $id);
        print_r($results);
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)) {       
            $url = $row['url'];

        } 
         return View::make('hello')->with('row', $url);
    }

}
```

I have also tried:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function showWelcome() {
        $id = intval($_GET['wab_id']);
        $results = DB::Table('films')->get()->where('wab_id', $id);
        print_r($results);
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)) {       
            $url = $row['url'];

        } 
         return View::make('hello')->with('row', $url);
    }

}
```

Only to be thrown the same error message and this is the only snippet that has not thrown the error but returns with a error of:

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function showWelcome() {
        $id = intval($_GET['wab_id']);
        $results = DB::Table("SELECT * FROM next WHERE wab_id=$id");
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)) {       
            $url = $row['url'];

        } 
         return View::make('hello')->with('row', $url);
    }

}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/', array(
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@showWelcome'
    ));
```

Comment: can you show the code for the route that you are passing the parameter into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was trying to pass an std Obj array to the view, but i had to set wab_id because if not i would get a undefined index of wab_id next i 
`$arrays = json_decode(json_encode($results), true);` in order to get the std array that i was getting with using the query into a multi array then  looped through the array and that worked

thanks everyone for your help.

**Controller**

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

        public function showWelcome(){
            $id = isset($_GET['wab_id'])?$_GET['wab_id']:"";

            $results = DB::Table('films')->where('wab_id', $id)->get();

            $arrays = json_decode(json_encode($results), true);

            foreach ( $arrays as $film ) {

          }
            return View::make('hello')->with('film', $film);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the order of the chaining to put the where() function before the get() function. Anything after get() will be applied to an Collection rather than the Query Builder.

Comment: thank you but would you happen to know why im given `mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given`

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use Eloquent's $results->toArray() function?

Comment: because it basically gives me the same error `Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a parameter through the URL try:

```
// routes.php
Route::get('/{wab_id}', array(
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@showWelcome'
));
```

Also, the where() constraint should be before the `get()` method.

Now you should be able to accept the URL parameter as an argument into your `HomeController#ShowWelcome` function

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function showWelcome($wab_id) {
        $id = $wab_id;

        // where() constraint before the `get()` method.
        $results = DB::Table('films')->where('wab_id','=', $id)->get();
        print_r($results);
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)) {       
            $url = $row['url'];

        } 
         return View::make('hello')->with('row', $url);
    }

}
```

Comment: `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException`

Comment: did you pass the id into the URL? , e.g. `/23`  or whatever the `id` value is that you want to pass into the URL

Comment: yea i passed an id into the Url "blah.com?id=266 and blah.com/266 and both returned with an error i believe its something to do with the route.

Answer (score 0):

You get a mysql_fetch_array error because when you messed up the order of the get() and where() functions

```
    //you did it like this 
    DB::table('films')->get()->where('wab_id','=', $id);
    //you did it like this, instead of
    DB::table('films')->where('wab_id','=', $id)->get();
```

the **get()** is ignored. that is why the result will not be an array;

**EDIT :**

If you use the toArray() helper function you wont need to encode and decode it as Json.

```
    //you can do so like this
    DB::Table('films')->where('wab_id','=', $id)->toArray();
    //or this if thats too long
    $result = DB::table('films')->where('wab_id','=', $id);
    $array = $result->toArray();
```